# Hydrator issue in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

### Pastebin

[HERE is my pastebin!](http://pastebin.com/26MJ0DQX)

---

I have three custom hydrators added to my `AggregateHydrator`:

```
$hydrator = new AggregateHydrator();
$hydrator->add(new ClassMethods());
$hydrator->add(new \Application\Hydrator\OrderedUserHydrator());
$hydrator->add(new \Application\Hydrator\ArrivedUserHydrator());
$hydrator->add(new \Application\Hydrator\FittedUserHydrator());
```

The problem I am having is that **`OrderedUserHydrator`** only seems to work when **`ArrivedUserHydrator`** does. Actually, **`OrderedUserHydrator`** should always be hydrating. But it isn't:

```
/var/www/zf-skeleton/module/Application/src/Application/Mapper/ZendDbSqlMapper.php:585:
object(Application\Model\Parts)[786]
  protected 'id' => string '16' (length=2)
  protected 'vehicle_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  protected 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  protected 'part_name' => string 'Test part' (length=9)
  protected 'ordered_from' => string 'A SUPPLIER' (length=10)
  protected 'ordered_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'arrived_user_id' => null
  protected 'fitted_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'ordered_date' => string '2016-04-06 00:00:00' (length=19)
  protected 'arrived_date' => null
  protected 'fitted_date' => string '2016-04-27 15:03:24' (length=19)
  protected 'ordered_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[803]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => null <!-- THIS SHOULD BE SET
      protected 'display_name' => null <!-- THIS SHOULD BE SET
  protected 'arrived_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[804]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => null
      protected 'display_name' => null
  protected 'fitted_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[805]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => string 'alex@home.com' (length=13)
      protected 'display_name' => string 'Alex Foobar' (length=13)
```

As soon as **`ArrivedUserHydrator`** is able to hydrate, **`OrderedUserHydrator`** works:

```
/var/www/zf-skeleton/module/Application/src/Application/Mapper/ZendDbSqlMapper.php:585:
object(Application\Model\Parts)[786]
  protected 'id' => string '16' (length=2)
  protected 'vehicle_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  protected 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  protected 'part_name' => string 'Test part' (length=9)
  protected 'ordered_from' => string 'A SUPPLIER' (length=10)
  protected 'ordered_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'arrived_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'fitted_user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected 'ordered_date' => string '2016-04-06 00:00:00' (length=19)
  protected 'arrived_date' => string '2016-04-27 15:01:29' (length=19)
  protected 'fitted_date' => string '2016-04-27 15:01:29' (length=19)
  protected 'ordered_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[803]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => string 'alex@home.com' (length=13)
      protected 'display_name' => string 'Alex Foobar' (length=13)
  protected 'arrived_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[804]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => string 'alex@home.com' (length=13)
      protected 'display_name' => string 'Alex Foobar' (length=13)
  protected 'fitted_user' =>
    object(Application\Model\User)[805]
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'username' => null
      protected 'email' => string 'alex@home.com' (length=13)
      protected 'display_name' => string 'Alex Foobar' (length=13)
```

Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated. I've been tearing my hair out.

---

My hydrators are as  follows:

**/home/user/development/zf-skeleton/module/Application/src/Application/Hydrator/OrderedUserHydrator.php:**

```
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Application\Model\User;

class OrderedUserHydrator extends ClassMethods
{
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object)
    {
        $userData = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $userData[substr($key, 12)] = $value;

            if ('ordereduser_' === substr($key, 0, 12)) {
                $userData[substr($key, 12)] = $value;
            }

        }

        $ordered_user = parent::hydrate($userData, new User());

        $object->setOrderedUser($ordered_user);

        return $object;
    }
}
```

**/home/user/development/zf-skeleton/module/Application/src/Application/Hydrator/ArrivedUserHydrator.php:**

```
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Application\Model\User;

class ArrivedUserHydrator extends ClassMethods
{
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object)
    {
        $userData = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $userData[substr($key, 12)] = $value;

            if ('arriveduser_' === substr($key, 0, 12)) {
                $userData[substr($key, 12)] = $value;
            }


        }

        $arrived_user = parent::hydrate($userData, new User());

        $object->setArrivedUser($arrived_user);

        return $object;
    }
}
```

**/home/user/development/zf-skeleton/module/Application/src/Application/Hydrator/FittedUserHydrator.php:**

```
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Application\Model\User;

class FittedUserHydrator extends ClassMethods
{
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object)
    {
        $userData = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $userData[substr($key, 11)] = $value;

            if ('fitteduser_' === substr($key, 0, 11)) {
                $userData[substr($key, 11)] = $value;
            }

        }

        $fitted_user = parent::hydrate($userData, new User());

        $object->setFittedUser($fitted_user);

        return $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"`OrderedUserHydrator` only seems to work when `ArrivedUserHydrator` does"* exactly mean? This description of your problem is a bit vague. Can you be more specific on what happens (expected vs actual behavior)?

Comment: `protected 'ordered_user' =>` object should be filled with data even when `protected 'arrived_user' =>` isn't.

Comment: Are those objects doctrine entities?

Comment: Nope they're just normal db Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in all hydrators. Remove this line from all hydrators and should work:

```
$userData[substr($key, 11)] = $value;
```

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you!